# "Listings" environment for GAP

Tags: listings, code

I was searching the web for a possible environment where I can put my GAP (Groups, Algorithms, Programming) codes. The most promising I saw was the "listings" package. But to my disappointment, this doesn't naturally recognize GAP codes.

Any other suggestions on this? Thanks!

P.S. This is my first time to write my codes in LaTeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Package `listings` provides an interface to add new languages. As starting point you can use the following example, that I constructed with a quick look at the [reference manual](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html) of [GAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAP_%28computer_algebra_system%29). The GAP code example is taken from the shortened documentation example [Fischer 23](http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/fischer.html).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
% http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html
\lstdefinelanguage{GAP}{%
  morekeywords={%
    Assert,Info,IsBound,QUIT,%
    TryNextMethod,Unbind,and,break,%
    continue,do,elif,%
    else,end,false,fi,for,%
    function,if,in,local,%
    mod,not,od,or,%
    quit,rec,repeat,return,%
    then,true,until,while%
  },%
  sensitive,%
  morecomment=[l]\#,%
  morestring=[b]",%
  morestring=[b]',%
}[keywords,comments,strings]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green!70!black},
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=GAP]
# http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/fischer.in
LoadPackage( "ctbllib" );
ct := CharacterTable( "Fi23" );;
permchar := Sum( Irr( ct ){[1,2,6]} );;
permchar[1];
nccl := NrConjugacyClasses( ct );;
ord3 := Filtered( [ 1 .. nccl ],
     i -> OrdersClassRepresentatives( ct )[i] = 3 );
permchar{ ord3 };
roots := [ 6 ];; 
for i in [ 1 .. nccl ] do
     if ForAny( Set( Factors( Size( ct ) ) ),
         p -> PowerMap( ct, p )[i] in roots ) then
       AddSet( roots, i );
     fi;
   od;  
roots;  
prop := Sum( roots, i -> 1 / SizesCentralizers( ct )[i] );
Int( 100 * prop );
LoadPackage( "atlasrep" );
gens := OneAtlasGeneratingSet( "Fi23", NrMovedPoints, 31671 );;
Fi23 := Group( gens.generators );;
SetSize( Fi23, Size( ct ) );
opdom := MovedPoints( Fi23 );;
found := false;;
repeat
     g := Random( Fi23 );
     ord := Order( g );  
     if ord mod 3 = 0 then
       h := g^( ord / 3 );
       if Number( opdom, i -> i^h = i ) = 324 then
         found := true;
       fi;
     fi;  
   until found;
N := Normalizer( Fi23, SubgroupNC( Fi23, [ h ] ) );;
# [...]
sct := CharacterTable( A );;
# To complete the next command you need to start GAP
# with at least -o 400M option
# During the computation of Irr(sct) you will get two info
# messages about computing class matrix for class of size >10^6
Irr( sct );;
Maximum( List( Irr( sct ), i -> i[1] ) );
# [...]
PermCharInfo( ct, ind ).ATLAS;
quit;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Update

The new maintainer Jobst Hoffmann has now added the language definition for GAL to `listings` 2013/08/05 v1.5a.

With

```
\usepackage{listings}[2013/08/05]
```

the language definition `\lstdefinelanguage{GAP}{...}[...]` is no longer necessary.